# How to find the referrer when a web service is called directly by java code in a batch job?

Tags: java, rest, ejb, http-referer

We are using a secured `Rest Service` which generates a `token` based on a user name, password and `referrer`.  It works fine when we run it from a Web project because it is clear the `referrer` is just the `url` of the web project.  We need to run the code in a batch job and we are getting an `invalid token error` and we suspect the issue is with the `referrer` value. Since there is no `url` involved in running the batch job what should we use for the `referrer` value?

The code which calls the `Rest Service` is generated by the `Rest Service` `WSDL` and is located in an `EJB` module.  The code is triggered by a `Quartz` timer.

EDIT:

I don't have control over how the request is sent.  All I can do is use the method provided by the java client created from the service wsdl. I also have no control over how the token is created.  The code which generates the token requires I pass it the referrer and it is used to generate the token. When the code is run in an app, then using the url of the app as the referrer works, the token is accepted. When the batch job runs there is no url, there is no browser involve, it is just code running on a server which executes the java method.

Comment: You can't guess the referrer. It is either set by the client or not. It is not a mandatory part of the http request. You should add it manually to the request. Actually the referrer is not typical for rest services, it is used by browsers when navigated from a link, althrough it is also set for ajax requesta.

Answer (score 0):

Doing some more research I found the code which generates the token will also accept the IP address which is what I think I have to do to use it in a batch job.